# photo2shape QGIS 2.1x

Tags: qgis, geolocation, photo2shape, exif

I'm stuck on a problem with photo2shape in QGIS 2.1x (I already tried several versions).

I installed Exif Reader and photo2shape worked fine for me. Since last week QGIS crashes as soon I start creating the photo point layer. I tried several QGIS versions (2.14, 2.16, 2.18) and reinstalled the exifread plugin too.

No idea how to proceed...